Commands in args not executing automatically, how to do so by editing only the YAML file?
I'm having an issue with my Kubernetes Pod YAML file. The commands specified in the args section are not executing automatically when the Pod starts. Instead, I have to manually run these commands each time.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
  namespace: default
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    node.kubernetes.io/instance-type: nice-gpu-machine
  containers:
  - args:
    - -c
    - |
      apt-get update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      yes | unminimize
      apt-get install -y byobu wget curl git vim nano jq unzip bzip2 tar gzip tmux htop tree net-tools man-db
      apt update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      apt install -y software-properties-common
      add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
      apt update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      apt install -y python3.11 python3.11-venv python3.11-dev python3.11-distutils
      apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssh-server
      sleep infinity
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    image: my-registry/my-image:latest
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: app
    resources:
      limits:
        nvidia.com/gpu: 8
        hugepages-2Mi: 5120Mi
      requests:
        memory: 8000Mi
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /checkpoints
        name: checkpoints-volume
      - mountPath: /code
        name: code-volume
      - mountPath: /data
        name: data-volume
      - name: dshm
        mountPath: /dev/shm
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
  - name: checkpoints-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: checkpoints-pvc
  - name: code-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: code-pvc
  - name: data-volume
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: data-pvc
  - name: dshm
    emptyDir:
      medium: Memory

I have two questions:

Is there anything wrong with my YAML file that's preventing the args commands from executing automatically?
If the YAML file is correct, would it be better to create a new Docker image with these commands pre-installed? If so, how should I approach this?

Solution 1 is strongly preferred as 2 is complicated and more time consuming than updating one YAML file e.g. pushing image building it and it might be huge.
Note: also posted at https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/help-with-kubernetes-pod-yaml-commands-in-args-not-executing-automatically-how-to-do-so-by-editing-only-the-yml-file/29388

That seems like a very foolish command to be wanting to run to begin with; containers should start quickly and run exactly what they always do. Move any updates to the actual image content outside this loop.

Concur with @jonrsharpe. Your command also assumes that the container's entrypoint is a shell. Usually this would be something of the form bin/sh -c "....".

You absolutely should move this setup into a Dockerfile.  You should almost never install software into a running container; this setup as you have it is prone to failing if you have network connectivity issues or if the remote repository rate-limits you, and it will be a very slow startup.  You should pretty much never make the main container command be a no-op sleep; have the container actually do the thing it's doing.

@jonrsharpe I agree, though, I don't have the power to do that in the compute cluster I'm using sadly and org I am at. Regardless, from a technical level, why wouldn't I be able to run these commands even if not best practices? The exact question (with an unambiguous solution I'm hoping) is, how do I run commands I want to run upon entry to my kubernetes container from a minimized pod?


Is there anything wrong with my YAML file that's preventing the args commands from executing automatically?

There's nothing wrong with the YAML. If I remove the irrelevant bits so that I can run it locally, giving me:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - -c
    - |
      apt-get update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      yes | unminimize
      apt-get install -y byobu wget curl git vim nano jq unzip bzip2 tar gzip tmux htop tree net-tools man-db
      apt update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      apt install -y software-properties-common
      add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
      apt update -y
      apt upgrade -y
      apt install -y python3.11 python3.11-venv python3.11-dev python3.11-distutils
      apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssh-server
      sleep infinity
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    image: docker.io/ubuntu:24.04
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: app

It runs without a problem. Running kubectl logs, I see all the expected output from your apt commands.
Your question doesn't include the output of kubectl logs. Are you sure the commands aren't running? Do you see any errors in the logs?
The way you've written your script, it will continue running even if a command fails, which means you could end up with a running container that is missing some or all of the expected packages.

If the YAML file is correct, would it be better to create a new Docker image with these commands pre-installed? If so, how should I approach this?

It usually makes sense to build a custom container image. Using something like Github actions or the automatic build service offered by docker hub or quay.io, you can have the image built for you automatically whenever you make changes.
Using a custom image means reduced startup time whenever you start your container, and it makes it easier to test outside of a kubernetes environment. As @DavidMaze points out, using a custom image makes your container startup more robust: once the image has been pulled successfully, it will always run, whereas your solution is vulnerable to failure due to network interruptions every time it runs.
